# Discord Bot Check Permissions In Kick Command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

This is my kick command. But i have been trying to make a command which checks if the member to be banned is a admin (Administrator permission)or not. I don,t get any error with the code below. But i am unable to find a code that does that.If i have made any mistakes please let me know so i can correct it both with the code and posting the question.

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def kick(context, member: discord.Member):

    if context.message.author.server_permissions.kick_members:

        await bot.say('You have kick Perms so now starting the command')
        if member== context.message.server.owner:
            await bot.say('U cant ban a moderator')
        else:
            await bot.say('Almost done!')
            time.sleep(1)
            try:
                await bot.kick(member)
                await bot.send_message(bot.get_channel('553090886683197451'),'has been kicked')
            except Exception:
                    await bot.say('the member is a mod or the bot has crashed')
    else:
        await bot.say("U don't perms :sweat_smile:")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, you have to describe your issue - do you get some error, unexpected result? Read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question - repeating requirements in comments and writing how long you deal with your issue is not helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the targets permissions the same way you're checking the authors permissions in your current code, using the [`sevrer_permissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.server_permissions) attribute:

```
from discord import Member
from discord.ext.commands import Bot, has_permissions, CheckFailure, BadArgument

bot = Bot("!")

@bot.command(pass_context=True, name="kick")
@has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick_command(ctx, *, target: Member):
    if target.server_permissions.administrator:
        await bot.say("Target is an admin")
    else:
        try:
            await bot.kick(target)
            await bot.say("Kicked")
        except Exception:
            await bot.say("Something went wrong")

@kick_command.error
async def kick_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, CheckFailure):
         await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "You do not have permissions")
    elif isinstance(error, BadArgument):
        await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "Could not identify target")
    else:
        raise error
```